# Storage of home SIM while abroad

Tags: international-travel, electronic-items

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I've always found stack exchange users pretty helpful so here goes.

I'm travelling from the UK to the Philippines, when I arrive at the Philippines I will buy a local SIM card for my phone (already unlocked) so I can communicate more cheaply with contacts in both the Philippines and back home.

My question is this... Where is a good place to keep the original SIM while it is out of the phone, which will help to prevent loss or data corruption? This applies to visiting any country really.

My first thought was my wallet, but it doesn't have any sealed pockets and I don't want to keep it with anything else in case I lose that (it would be my luck). There are small storage things (for pills, matches etc. that would fit) that you can attach to keyrings but as I won't have my house or car keys with me I won't have anything to attach it to.

Any ideas? I need somewhere safe to keep it ready for when I arrive back home.

Thanks

Comment: It's not suitable for all phones, but on my LG G3 there's about enough room to store an additional SIM card between the battery and the back cover, while still securing it back in place fully. As long as you're not in the habit of dropping your phone (hard enough for the back cover to come loose/off) I've always found that to be sufficient.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Interesting approach thanks - when I had a Nokia 3210 I used to do that with bank notes! Not that I ever had many.

Answer (score 3):

I have a small collection of SIM cards and I use a [SIM card wallet](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dmobile&field-keywords=sim+card+storage+case) to hold them.  They gave me mine at a China Unicom store, but I see these for sale in mobile phone accessory shops sometimes. This might be overkill for just one card, though.

SIM cards are tough, there aren't many ways to damage one (one of mine has been cut twice, normal->micro->nano size, with the plastic ground to nano thickness using a Dremel tool; it still works fine) and they (generally) aren't RFID responders so they aren't in need of much protection from anything.  You only need to have a way to avoid losing the card and the tool you need to get the SIM tray out of the phone.

Comment: I don't find them very tough, in particular not the ones that are combined normal/micro/nano.

Comment: I always pop the nano-size SIM, making it as tough as any other nanoSIM, and use an adapter for my microSIM phone.  Unlike micro->mini adapters, good nano->micro (and nano->mini) adapters seem to work pretty well since the reduced thickness of the nanoSIM makes it easier to keep in place.  The adapter lives in the wallet too.

Answer (score 3):

Most SIMs come in wallet sized card, that you pop the SIM out of.  I simply pop my regular SIM into the hole left in the card of the SIM I just bought (they usually are tight enough to stay), put it back in its packaging and store it in my briefcase with my electronic accessories.

When I leave, I simply reverse the process, which means I have the SIM details with it, in case I might be planning a return trip to that country in the not too distant future.

I always back up contacts, photos, docs before traveling somewhere that I am planning on getting a new SIM, cause sometimes while setting up you just push the wrong button :(

Answer (score 2):

Your cheapest/safest option will probably be to buy a new wallet once you get to the Philippines.

Obviously, you should look for one that has a zipper pouch for coins or the like.

Otherwise, you might consider leaving your UK SIM at home!

Answer (score 2):

I usually put it in a zip-lock bag (always good to carry extra bags when traveling) and keep it with the rest of my electronics/chargers/etc...

Another option I've used is to stash it in one of the [little plastic cases](http://images.tapeonline.com/products/generic-memory-accessories-sd-card-case-large-3219.jpg) SD cards come in. Even if the SIM card is smaller than an SD card, it will be fine in there.